# What can I do if I deleted few objects from the interface builder by mistake?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

can I bring it back?? I'm using nib files and I deleted from the nib file few objects in the document outline ://

Please tell me I can re:do this...I know i should of use version control, I will start use it right away, but is there another way to do this?

help

Comment: Restore them from your backups.

Comment: @HotLicks how do I do this please?

Comment: This is an excellent point to realize that using source control systems such as Git is an important part of developing software, gee Xcode will set that up for you when you create a project. Also an off-site repo such as GitHub or BitBucket. Time Machine is easy to setup/use and is a good idea.

Comment: Well you open Tower or whatever tool you use to interact with your backups and restore the appropriate files.

Comment: Select the file, show on the Version Editor, select the last version that has the code and restore.

Comment: @HotLicks isn't it another way to restore my changes rather some backups control? since I didnt use it, I know now that I should use tools for that, but can I bring back the damage?

Comment: Can you restore them from the Trash?

Comment: @NobodyNada is there a trash in xcode?

Comment: Never mind, I misread your question.  I thought you deleted the nib file itself.

Comment: @NobodyNada Either you can immediately (right now) start controlling your code (and other files) or you can wait until you have another loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Edit > Undo.
2. Start using Version Control.